# Computing a summation of products more efficiently via factorization

Tags: summation, products

Let $P = \{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ (may be a multiset). I wish to compute $\sum\limits_{S \subseteq P \\ |S| = k} \prod\limits_{i \in S} i \prod\limits_{i \not\in S} (1-i)$ in an efficient manner. The naive approach takes time proportional to $\binom{n}{k},$ which makes it too slow for the case $n=200, k=100.$

The case where all elements of $P$ are equal is trivial, but even the case where $n$ elements are $p$ and $n$ elements are $q$ reduces to computing $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}p^i (1-p)^{n-i} q^{k-i} (1-q)^{n-k+i},$ for which the evaluation of the tricky summation $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{k-i} x^i$ is required.

Comment: Nice – I didn't know that you can get a large font-size for two-line limits by using `\\ ` instead of `\atop`. Ah, but they don't get centred properly then.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor this one element at a time. First let’s simplify the problem by dividing by $\prod_{i\in P}(1-i)$; then you just need to determine the sum

$$
a(Q,k)=\sum_{S\subseteq Q\atop|S|=k}\prod_{i\in S}i
$$

for $Q=f(P)$, with $f(x)=\frac x{1-x}$. Start with the first element and write

$$
a(Q,k)=q_1a\left(Q\setminus\{q_1\},k-1\right)+a\left(Q\setminus\{q_1\},k\right)\;,
$$

and continue recursively for all elements. That yields a Pascalesque triangle in which you only have to perform $O\left(n^2\right)$ operations. Instead of just adding two elements as you do for Pascal’s triangle, here you multiply the left element with a factor $q_i$ associated with the row before adding it to the right element.

Another way to think about it is in terms of generating functions: You’re looking for the coefficient of $x^k$ in

$$
\prod_{i\in Q}(1+ix)\;,
$$

or, in your original formulation with $P$, the coefficient of $x^k$ in

$$
\prod_{i\in P}(1-i+ix)\;.
$$

Of course you can also write the triangle approach directly in terms of $P$:

$$
a(P,k)=p_1a\left(P\setminus\{p_1\},k-1\right)+(1-p_1)a\left(P\setminus\{p_1\},k\right)\;;
$$

it just seemed easier to think of it at first if we only have factors for the selected elements.

Comment: I found that recursion, but the time estimate seems to still be $\binom{n}{k}.$ Denoting $T(n,k)$ as the time taken to calculate $a(P,k)$ when $|P|=n,$ we have $T(n,k) = T(n-1,k-1) + T(n-1,k),$ which has the solution $T(n,k) = \binom{n}{k}.$

Comment: I see how to make the recursion $O(n^2)$ now. You left out the important step of computing from the bottom up: compute $a(\emptyset, 0),$ then $a(\{p_n\}, 0), a(\{p_n\}, 1),$ then $a(\{p_{n-1}, p_n\}, 0), a(\{p_{n-1}, p_n\}, 1), a(\{p_{n-1}, p_n\}, 2),$ then ...

Comment: @Displayname: I don't understand. How other than from the bottom up could you apply the recurrence relation? (Also, I thought that the analogy to Pascal's triangle made it quite explicit how to do the calculation. How do you generate Pascal's triangle by adding two elements, if not from the bottom up (or, as it's usually oriented, from the tip down)?)

Comment: Given the recursion $f(m,n) = af(m-1,n-1)+bf(m-1,n),$ one approach is to compute $f(m-1,n-1), f(m-1,n)$ using the recursion and then perform the necessary arithmetic to get $f(m,n).$ I didn't consider the bottom up approach until I remembered that you do the same with linear recurrences.

Comment: @Displayname: I'm afraid we're talking past each other. I don't see what else you could do than compute $f(m-1,n-1)$, $f(m-1,n)$ using the recursion and then perform the necessary arithmetic to get $f(m,n)$. I get the impression that perhaps you mean something else: That it hadn't occurred to you to memoize the intermediate values and you were recalculating them each time you needed them at some stage. That would indeed be very inefficient. But that's not a question of top-down or bottom-up; it's a question of not calculating the same thing more than once.

Comment: @Displayname: In other words: There are only $O\left(n^2\right)$ different values to be calculated here, no matter how you organize the calculation. The only thing you can do wrong to get complexity greater than $O\left(n^2\right)$ is to calculate them more than once.

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of generating functions here.
Suppose we are given two lists or multisets of equal length
$\, P = (p_1,\ldots,p_n)\,$ and $\, Q = (q_1,\dots,q_n).\,$
Use the useful notation $\,[n] := \{1,\ldots,n\}.\,$
Define the sum of products
$$ a_k(P,Q) = a_k := \sum_{S\subseteq [n],|S|=k}
 \prod_{i\in S}P_i \prod_{i\notin S}Q_i. $$
Define the generating function of $\,a_k\,$ to be
the polynomial
$$ f(x) := \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(P,Q)x^k = \prod_{i=1}^n (x\,p_i+y_i) $$
where the equality to the product follows from the
definition of $\,a_k\,$ and the distributivity of
multiplication over addition. We want to calculate some
of the coefficients of $\,f(x).\,$ That is,
 $\,a_k=[x^k]f(x).\,$ An efficient approach is to truncate
$\,f(x)\,$ and keep coefficients up to order $\,x^k\,$
when evaluating the product. This is a generalization of
the binomial theorem for evaluating $\,(p+q)^n\,$ using
binomial coefficients and computing them by the usual
Pascal triangle recursion.